# how to run multiple functions inside loop at once in jquery

Tags: jquery, comet, long-polling

```
 var id = [10,5,3]; //array

  $.each(id, function(k, v){
      console.log(v);//10 5 3
      ckit.isRead(v);
    });
```

I need the function within $.each loop  `ckit.isRead(v);` to run at once for all the items in the array.

Normally, the function will run after a loop for a value in the array completes. But I want to be able to know, total values in the array. and then execute the function separately for each.

Lets say  `ckit.isRead(v);` is an ajax call. instead of firing once ajax at a time for each value in the id array. 3 calls should be fired. How can I achieve this?

The reason I'm opting for this way is:

I'm using comet long polling to check is there's new notification. How the cmet long polling works here is, when first call is fired and no new notification is wont return any data and in the console, the xhr(url) status will show pending. Only when data is returned the request will complete and start a new request again. In this case, I'm afraid the second item in the array will only get called when the first item's loop completed.

Is there a better way of doing things with comet long polling where item to check is array?

Comment: You can't fire a function 3 times "at once". You have to do that inside a loop. Whether you count array size and run a "for loop"  and call `ckit.isRead(v);` inside that loop or do it the way you already are doing right now, it will ideally and practically fire once at a time for each "loop iteration".

Comment: @sumitbadaya, pls refer my edited post..